# How to create a Google Cloud Launcher package?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-launcher

Google Cloud has the click-to-deploy "Cloud Launcher" that makes it easy to deploy software packages on VMs. My company is interested in creating one of these click-to-deploy packages.

What is the process to create one of these packages? Is this sort of thing open to any developer? And how could I get in contact with the right people for this sort of thing?

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you have any luck submitting a request through the form or find anything to list a deployment in the marketplace? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create such packages yourself. Please get in touch with Google via [this form](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) to discuss your proposal.